# App not working if dependency left blank, working if dependency completely removed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a simple Angular app, calling a controller, which in turn calls a service. This service then loops through an array and returns a few strings.

If I leave the dependencies on the angular.module empty in the controller and the service it does not return the array:

app.js

```
angular.module('list_app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/list', {
          templateUrl: 'views/template.html',
          controller: 'ListCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/list_page'});
});
```

Controller

```
angular.module('list_app', [])
   .controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Service', function ($scope, Service) {

    Service.getList($scope);

}]);
```

Service

```
angular.module('list_app', [])
  .factory(
'Service', function Service() {

     function getList($scope){
         var listRules = $scope.rules=['Test One', 'Test Two'];

         var arrayLength = listRules.length;

         for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
             return(listRules[i]);
         }
     };

     return {
         getList: getList
     }
   });
```

But if I remove the dependancy [] from the controller and service, it works fine...

Like this:

```
angular.module('list_app', )...
```

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you only need to initialize your module once.

This happens when you use the curly braces:

```
angular.module('list_app', ['ngRoute'])
```

Afterwards you dont need them anymore as the module already is initialized.
So afterwards you can just call in all subsequent calls (controller, service):

```
angular.module('list_app')
```

Comment: ah... so I'm initializing it multiple times? Cheers! Could I declare it as a variable in app.js and then obly refer to that variable in my controller and service?

So var app =  angular.module('list_app', ['ngRoute']), and then just  call 'app' in the service and controller?

Comment: @Daft Yup! I dropped an example of this in my answer. You can see additional examples on angular's site as well.

Comment: Yes you could do this. But AFAIK its an Anti-Pattern. You should rather chain the calls. angular.module('list_app', ['ngRoute']).config(...).controller(...).service(...)

Answer (score 1):

**Missing Include?**

In order to use `ngRoute` you need to include angular-route before you load your controller. That would be the following (as of right now):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular-route.min.js" />
```

You can also download the minified or full version of this library from the [angular site](http://angularjs.org).

**Multiple Module Definitions**

Another thing I noticed about the code is it looks like you are calling "angular.module" multiple times. You should only do this once, something like:

```
var list_app = angular.module('list_app', ['ngRoute']);

// define the service as an example:
list_app.factory('MyService', function Routine() {
});

// then define the controller
list_app.controller('MainController, ['$scope', function ($scope) {
}]);
```

The point is after you define the module once - you should use that reference to make any further declarations! This also might help fix your issue.

**Side Note**

One more comment is that when you try to inject a dependency that angular can't find the most common error you will see in the console is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] (etc.)
```

Whenever you see a message like this you should start to look at whether or not you are missing script includes and checking to make sure these are in the correct order.

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate the detailed answer!